# Open native camera from react native

Tags: ios, camera, reactjs, native, react-native

I am new to react native and need your help. I am new to react native I am trying to integrate blink sdk with my react native app. I have exposed a native method to react native js using `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()`. JS button click is invoking this native method. Now from this native method I want to open camera using:

```
/* Allocate and present the scanning view controller */

    UIViewController<PPScanningViewController>* scanningViewController = [coordinator cameraViewControllerWithDelegate:self];

   scanningViewController.autorotate = YES;
   scanningViewController.supportedOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
```

Now there are two problems:

1. If I run it just like that, it gives me red screen saying "invoke the method on main thread".
2. Now to run it on main thread, I added `-(dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
   {
   return dispatch_get_main_queue();
   }`

Still it is not running and saying not present in view hierarchy. Please help.

Comment: Where are you pushing/presenting controller?